# How to implement callbacks for intents in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, android-intent, callback, xamarin.android

I tried to implement a platform-independent wrapper for sharing files that takes a filename and an `Action` as a callback. Despite it does work, I am not content with my Android solution at all.

What I am currently doing is: I am registering my callback with my `MainActivity`, which returns an ID which I can use to identify the callback

```
int callbackId = MainActivity.Instance.RegisterCallback(completionHandler);
```

Then I start `ActionShare` intent with

```
MainActivity.Instance.StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select App"), 123 | (callbackId << 8));#
```

The `123` is my identifier for the action.

In my `MainActivity` in `OnActivityResult` I am getting and calling my callback with

```
var callbackId = (requestCode & 0b1111111100000000) >> 8;

if (this.RemoveCallbackById(callbackId, out var callback))
{
    callback();
}
```

Is there a better way implementing callbacks for intents in Xamarin.Android? I believe there must be, but being constrained to passing only a single 16 bit integer to `StartActivityForResult` that will be passed to `OnActivityResult` the possibilities seem quite limited to me.

Comment: Pretty sure that is the only way